# UIView layer problems

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, uiview

I have a problem with UIViews, I have a white UIView with the frame 240*320, and a black UIView with the frame 480*20 and I add the white view to my landscape mainView which is 480*320 and then I add the black view to the white view, and the black view is not only above the white view but also above the mainView, and I don't want to be above the mainView, does anybody know a solution?, this is the code:

```
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 320)];
    UIView *otherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 20)];
    [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [otherView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [aView addSubview:otherView];
    [[self view] addSubview:aView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

```
aView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this thing to manage views.

[self.view bringsubviewtofront:uiview];
and also use the 
[self.view bringsubviewtoback:uiview];